# Disable tracking code automatically injected into CloudPages?

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

Has anyone had any experience disabling the tracking code injected into CloudPages created with the newer Content Builder tools?

It adds an event handler on every link for tracking clicks.

It was problematic for me in a custom profile center, since it unconditionally adds jQuery.  I was using anchor tags and handlers to hide and show content on the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//mc.exacttarget.com/cloudpages/utilities/t.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ctx=new Fuel.TrackingContext(999999,99999);
    var t=new Fuel.Tracking(ctx,{siteid:'123456',pageid:'123',isMobile:'false'});
    t.wrapLinks(null,'CLOUDPAGESCLICK');
    t.addRawEvent('CLOUDPAGESVISIT',{pageid:'123'});
    t.send();
</script>
```

Can it be disabled somehow?  Perhaps by Business Rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had the same issue and have had many discussions with Global support as well as my Account Rep and the Director in charge of development of Cloud Pages.

From what I was able to discern, the choice is either to completely remove the tracking from ALL pages/microsites, or those sciprts will be automatically added on all the pages.

I have even attempted using ServerSide scripts to remove these, but the scripts are added after all the user scripts are run - so this was a no go.

I attempted putting a client side Javascript snippet in to remove this, but I have had no luck as my disabling it doesn't seem to prevent it from being used initially. This may be a way to [explore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182840/removing-or-replacing-a-stylesheet-a-link-with-javascript-jquery) as I have not found definitive proof this may not solve the issue.

I wish I had a better answer, but it appears unless you want to disable tracking universally and manually add click tracking, you will need to allow this on all pages hosted in SFMC.

Comment: I spent over 40 hours on a coding a custom pref center remotely (loaded via httpget()).  I deployed the final code in the page and nothing worked.  Very frustrating.  Made me want to put everything in a Content Area.  I tried all of the unbinding tricks I could find.

Comment: I did something similar (in development time) building out a site to generate content for an external service (basically auto creating signatures for email based on user input and stored data - I know, there are many better ways, but it was at request of the business) and it got all sort of screwed up because the links were being parsed with click tracking, which broke the link when used outside the LP.