# Can we prevent any additional JS being inserted into a CloudPage?

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

This is a follow up from [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/186973/disable-tracking-code-automatically-injected-into-cloudpages) 3 years ago, I can see MC allows us to disable link tracking now however it still injects some code at the end of the page which is breaking our use case for using Landing Pages as a webhook.

The page returns the following output, I only defined the JSON object on the first line... the remaining lines have been added by Marketing Cloud.

Is there a way we can disable this? As mentioned I already have page tracking disabled.

```
{"message_id":"12347898754"}
<script>
    (function(a,m,i,g,o,s){o=a.createElement(g);s=a.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];o.src=m.origin+m.pathname+"/_t?eventType=CLOUDPAGESVISIT";o.width=0;o.height=0;o.style.display="none";s.appendChild(o);})(document,window.location,"body","img");
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting up the page as a 'Code Resource'? That should remove any of the added scripts, etc. But mind you this is only for resources or web-app esque pages. This will not work well if you are trying to display anything inside the browser.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Not sure why I didn't think of this. Please turn this into the answer. I literally needed the page to return a JSON feed so this fits within the limitations you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to create the page as a 'Code Resource' page. That should remove any of the added scripts, etc. that SFMC adds to CloudPages. Your use case fits in perfectly for what this option was created to allow.

Code Resource pages will not work well if you are trying to display anything inside the browser as this is not what they are designed to do and should not be used as anything 'human facing'.